# Couchdb replication file size

Tags: couchdb

I have a production couchdb server which gets compacted on a weekly basis.
It goes from 30MB to 15MB when compacted. But when I run replicate to a remote server, the file size on that server is 30MB.

How is this possible ? Im replicating a compacted version so it should be 15MB on the other end.

Is it also safe to compact "bloated" replicated data on a remote server and both will not have a "conflict" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication uses a number of _bulk_doc requests to send over all documents. Each request will produce some “garbage” data, as the underlying b+-tree is being rewritten to accommodate each new batch of documents.

It is safe to compact the replication target. Compaction has no semantic effect on any of your data. You can safely run it any time.